# combination of two DF, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two df,

First df

```
A B C
1 1 3
1 1 2
1 2 5
2 2 7
2 3 7
```

Second df

```
B D
1 5
2 6
3 4
```

The column `B`has the same meaning in the both dfs. What is the most easy way add column `D` to the corresponding values in the first df? Output should be:

```
A B C D
1 1 3 5
1 1 2 5
1 2 5 6
2 2 7 6
2 3 7 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a 'left' [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) in your case on column 'B':

```
In [206]:

df.merge(df1, how='left', on='B')
Out[206]:
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  3  5
1  1  1  2  5
2  1  2  5  6
3  2  2  7  6
4  2  3  7  4
```

Another method would be to set 'B' on your second df as the index and then call [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map):

```
In [215]:

df1 = df1.set_index('B')
df['D'] = df['B'].map(df1['D'])
df
Out[215]:
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  3  5
1  1  1  2  5
2  1  2  5  6
3  2  2  7  6
4  2  3  7  4
```